# Hive Start Up Time Manifolds Greater than Execution Time

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, bigdata, hadoop2

The time taken by hive to launch a mapreduce job was manifolds higher than the time taken by hadoop to actually execute it. 
This is the table details on which the query is being fired.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE A
(
    user_id string,
    stage strig,
    url string
)

PARTITIONED BY (dt string , id string)
```

All the data for table is stored in S3 and each day there will be around 2000 unique id i.e 2000 partitions being added daily. And we can assume that each partition has on a average 100MB gzip compressed data. 
Now when I run a query like "`SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM A  WHERE dt>='20150101' and dt <= '20150401'`" ie over a period of 3 months approx 60000 partitions it takes hive approximately 2 hrs to launch the map reduce job and the launched job just finishes in 20 min.
 So was wondering if someone can help me in understanding what hive is doing in this 2 hrs ? 
Would really appreciate some help here . Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: How long for an `EXPLAIN SELECT...` i.e. just parsing the query, accessing Metastore for information about table and partitions, accessing HDFS+S3 to list the files involved, checking statistics (if any) and then defining the execution plan?

Comment: Any chance that some partitions are locked by another query (e.g. an `INSERT` or `ALTER`) so that `SELECT` is waiting for a green light? Cf. `SHOW LOCKS` command.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter no there are no write permissions to this table as this a raw log table. I guess the accessing HDFS+S3 to list the files involved is taking a lot of time as i run the query in DEBUG mode i'm getiing a lot of statements like "Adding input file...."

Comment: `SHOW LOCKS` is not about permissions on *files*, it's about *Hive Metastore* consistency. E.g. you cannot drop a table while someone else is running a SELECT, and vice-versa.